# IVP $x(y-z) z_x + y(z-x) z_y = z(x-y) \; ; \; z=t $ over the initial Curve : $C : x=t, y = 2t/(t^2-1) \; 0 < t < 1$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

**Exercise :**

> Solve the IVP :
>   $$\begin{cases} x(y-z) z_x + y(z-x) z_y = z(x-y) \; ; \; z=t \\ C : x=t, y = 2t/(t^2-1) \; \; \; 0 < t < 1 \end{cases}$$

**Attempt :**

We yield the differential problem :

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x(y-z)} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y(z-x)} = \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z(x-y)}$$

and then we'll calculate two integral curves, $z_1, z_2$.

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x(y-z)} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y(z-x)} \Rightarrow \int y(z-x)\mathrm{d}x = \int x(y-z) \mathrm{d}y$$ $$\implies$$ $$z_1 = \frac{x^2y}{2} + \frac{xy^2}{2} - 2xyz $$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x(y-z)} = \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z(x-y)} \Rightarrow \int z(x-y)\mathrm{d}x = \int x(y-z) \mathrm{d}z$$
$$\implies$$
$$z_2 = \frac{x^2z}{2} + \frac{xz^2}{2} - 2xyz $$

We have the parameters of the initial curve $C$ as the point vector :

$$C : r_C(t) = \bigg(t,\frac{2t}{t^2-1}, t\bigg) \; 0 < t <1$$

and then we yield the system :

$$\begin{cases} Z_1 = \frac{2t^3}{(t^2-1)^2} - \frac{3t^3}{t^2-1}  \ Z_2 = t^3 - \frac{4t^3}{t^2-1} \end{cases}

**Question - Problem :** Now, in this particular step, I have to "get rid" of the variable $t$ by finding a connection between $Z_1, Z_2$, in order to replace the curves back and calculate a general solution. But in this particular case **I haven't been able to find a connection between them**. Is my solution mistaken at any part ? If not, how to proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x(y-z)} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y(z-x)} = \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z(x-y)}$$
$$\frac{d(x+y)}{z(y-x)} =  \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z(x-y)}$$
$$\int {d(x+y)} =  -\int dz$$
$$ \implies x+y+z=c_1$$

---

Edit

As @Lutzl has pointed out it's more simple ( and far better ) to do this
$$\frac{y\,dx}{xy(y-z)}=\frac{x\,dy}{xy(z-x)}=\frac{dz}{z(x-y)} $$

$$\implies \frac{y\,dx+x\,dy}{xy(y-x)}=\frac{dz}{z(x-y)}\iff \frac{d(xy)}{xy}+\frac{dz}{z}=0,$$
$$c_2=xyz$$

---

Another way

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x(y-z)} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y(z-x)} $$

$$y(z-x)dx= {x(y-z)} dy $$
But 
$$z=c_1-x-y$$
$$y(c_1-x-y-x)dx= {x(y-(c_1-x-y))} dy $$
Rearrange terms
$$-(x+y)^2dx+x^2dx+c_1ydx=(x+y)^2dy-y^2dy-c_1xdy$$
$$x^2dx+c_1(ydx+xdy)=(x+y)^2(dy+dx)-y^2dy$$
$$x^2dx+c_1d(xy)=(x+y)^2(d(x+y))-y^2dy$$
Thats easy to integrate
$$c_1xy+c_2=x^2y+y^2x$$
$$c_2=xy(y+x-c_1)$$
$$c_2=-xyz$$
$$c_2=xyz$$
If I made no mistakes.......

Comment: Yet another very helpful integral tip ! Thanks !

Comment: yw @Rebellos ...

Comment: Still though, how would you continue by finding an integral curve $z_2$ such that we'd be able to solve the system of the initial curve ? Would it be by applying the same trick or by substituting $c_1$ ?

Comment: I didn't mean that. Let's say I want to compute a second integral, as you did, how would I proceed ? How do you "do" that step  : $$\frac{d(x+y)}{z(y-x)} =  \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z(x-y)}$$

Comment: I simplifir by $x-y$ and alzo by $z$ then simply integrate...@Rebellos

Comment: You can shorten the computation for the second constant as follows:$$
\frac{y\,dx}{xy(y-z)}=\frac{x\,dy}{xy(z-x)}=\frac{dz}{z(x-y)}
\implies
\frac{y\,dx+x\,dy}{xy(y-x)}=\frac{dz}{z(x-y)}\iff \frac{d(xy)}{xy}+\frac{dz}{z}=0,
$$
so that in total $xyz=c_2$.

Comment: @LutzL yes surely..I was just asking myself if I could shorten my calculations ...

Comment: I will add your observation @lutsl